# Copy-Paste Multiple columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy selected columns from a sheet of one workbook to a sheet of another workbook. There are 10 columns but I need to copy just 4 and paste them in t another. Here's the code

```
Sub CopyCoverage()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\testing\abc.xlsm")
Set y = ThisWorkbook

x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate  // Here I need to select just 4 columns but it selects everything
Range("A65536").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row

Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("e65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("H1:H" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("g65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("I1:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("i65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

How can i write this in a general syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @phil652 What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

try to do not use .select and activecell

```
Sub CopyCoverage()

Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet, LastRow&

Workbooks.Open ("C:\testing\abc.xlsm")

Set x = Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = x.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

x.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("H1:H" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
x.Range("I1:I" & LastRow).Copy y.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Also, if table is dynamic (columns can be not in place where they must be, e.g. data in columns "B" was shifted to column "C"), then you can use ".find" method to get required columns (search in header) which is required to be copied

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try using a better range specification first? You can get rid of your code that finds the LastRow.

```
Application.Intersect(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ActiveWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1)), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Copy
```

The code above will select all of the data in column A whether it is contiguous or not. Change the second coordinate in the Cells() function to change columns. So Cells(1,1) = A1, Cells(2, 1) = A2, Cells(1, 2) = B1, etc.

Next, you need to activate ThisWorkbook in a separate line. Something like:

```
y.Activate
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Then go back and do the other three columns:

```
x.Activate
Application.Intersect(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2)), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Copy
y.Activate
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

And so on until you're happy. Hope that helps!
Matt, via ExcelArchitect.com

Comment: there is no need activate ThisWorkbook in a separate line, user3812709 do it in a proper way, result will be the same but with less coding